# Django model relationship with circular relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django and trying to understand the model relationships, here is my use case:

I have a `Creator` object which can create multiple `Listing` under a `Category`. `Category` can have multiple `Listing`s from multiple `Creator`s.

Creator -- Creates a Listing about a service -- under a Category or multiple Category

I am trying to find the thought process behind picking the correct relationship while defining this kind circular  relationship.  Which one of the model should go first? Is it Category which is first and Creator second and Listing at the end, is Creator, Category and Listing all belong to a Many to Many relationship, if then how are they linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a circular relationship, this should cover your use case:

```
class Creator:
    ...


class Category:
    ...


class Listing:
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Creator, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ManyToMany(Category)
```

I am assuming that a `Listing` can be under multiple `Category`s. If each listing can only have one `Category`, the second (`category`) relation must be a `ForeignKey` too.

Comment: Let's say the Creator is making a  Listing  about a service called  Plumbing, it could be under two different Categories, Commercial plumbers or Residential plumbers. In that case how do we go about it.

Comment: The `Listing` model has a M2M relation to `Category` in my answer, so a `Listing` object can have one or more `Category`s and any `Category` can have zero or more `Listing`s. Each `Listing` has exactly one `Creator` and a `Creator` can have zero or more listings.

Answer (score -1):

In Django Models there are three types of relationships.

**one to one** - when one entity is unique to other entity
**Example**: A user model can be in one to one relationship to customer model.
Every customer is unique user

**many to many** - When one entity can has relationship with many other entities and vice versa.
**Example** : pizza and toppings,
pizza can have many toppings, and same topping can be applied on various pizza

**one to many** - also called **foreign key** in Django  when a single entity is related to many other entities but vice versa is not true.

**Example**: your Use case applies here.
A creator can create multiple listings but a single listing can be mapped to single creator only, not multiple creator.

Comment: Amandeep, are you suggesting my use case fall under one to many for Creator and Listing, how about Category?

Comment: for category - It depends on your requirement.

one category can be assosiated with many listings (one to many)
if one listing can have multiple categories also (many to may)